# Qusetion about Zero divisors in a polynomial rings

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

Let $x^4-16$ be an element of the polynomial ring $E= \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and use the bar notation to denote passage to the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^4-16)$. Prove that $\bar{(x-2)}$ and $\bar{(x+2)}$ are zero divisors in $\bar E$. So basically i need to show that $\bar{(x-2)} \cdot \bar{(x+2)} = 0$ but $\bar{(x-2)} \not= 0$ and $\bar{(x+2)} \not= 0$ will that be ok. And also one thing that i do not understand does the set $ \bar E$ = $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^4-16)$

Comment: For your last question, see [here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~sullivan/4034s_wi13.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

$x^4 - 16 = (x^2 - 4)(x^2 + 4) = (x-2)(x+2)(x^2+4)$, and taking the "bar" of this allows you to conclude, as the quotient map "bar taking" is a morphism of rings...

More precisely, taking the bar gives $$0 = \overline{x^4 - 16} = \overline{(x-2)(x+2)(x^2+4)} = \overline{(x-2)}\times \overline{(x+2)} \times \overline{(x^2+4)}$$ so that $$ 0 = (\overline{x}-2)(\overline{x}+2)(\overline{x}^2 + 4).$$ This shows that $\overline{x}-2$ and $\overline{x}+2$ are zero-divisor, by definition of being a zero divisor : an element $x$ of a ring $A$ is a zero-divisor if there is a $b\not=0$ such that $ab=0$.

Indeed, $(\overline{x}-2)(\overline{x}^2 + 4)\not=0$ and $(\overline{x}+2)(\overline{x}^2 + 4)\not=0$.

Comment: i understand the multiplication process, but what do you mean by taking the bar of this allows me to conclude as the quotient map... i do not get that can you elaborate a little please.

Comment: then i had that sorry man. I had that all along then thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to show that the product of the two is $0$. What you need to show is that (for each of the two) there is some non-zero element such that the product is $0$.

To find such polynomials note that $(x-2)$ and $x+2$ are divisors of $x^4-16$. Calculate the respective co-factor and you are done.

Comment: what do you mean by calculate the respective co-factor

Comment: By the co-factor I mean the element $q$ such that $(x-2)q  = x^4 -16$ (and alike for the other); in other words the quotient of the division of $x^4 -16$ by $x-2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ Let $\,f(x)= x^4\!-16.$ By the Factor Theorem $\,f(2)=0\,\Rightarrow\,f = (x\!-\!2)\, g$ for some $\,g \in \Bbb Z[x].\,$ In the quotient ring this becomes $\ \bar f = (\bar x-2)\,\bar g,$ and neither factor $= 0\,$ (else $\,f\mid x\!-\!2\,$ or $\,f\mid g)$